# List view image from web showing error using Android Studio

Tags: android, image-processing, android-listview

I have a `listView` where I display the profile picture of the person (a sort of school social media) and I store the link to those Images in a SQL database with their name and 2 other parameters.

Here is my `custom adapter`:

```
class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public customAdapter(Context context, String[] friends) {
    super(context, R.layout.customrow, friends);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyDBHandler  dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getContext(), null, null, 1);
   Product product;
    LayoutInflater myinfl = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customview = myinfl.inflate(R.layout.customrow, parent, false);
    String singlefooditem  = getItem(position);
    TextView name = (TextView)customview.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)customview.findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    product = dbHandler.findProductName(singlefooditem);
   try {
        URL url = new URL(product.getImage());
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        img.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }catch (IOException e){

    }

    name.setText(singlefooditem);
    return customview;
}
```

Thats my  `logcat:`

```
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2532)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2262)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1391)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: [Check](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the stacktrace doesn't include the real error, which appears to be that you're trying to perform network activity on the main (UI) thread, which is a big no-no. Either perform this work in a new thread, or use the Android [ImageManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager) class to do all the hard work for you.

Comment: So I should just use the runnable thread? Won't this cause too many threads running at once in bigger lists.

Comment: Well, the threads will only be started when the list item comes into view so you shouldn't have too many at once, but you should definitely cache the image once downloaded or it will download every time the item comes into view. Again, the ImageManager handles both downloading and caching so I personally use this most of the time now.

Answer (score 1):

you should implement a AsyncTask class (which generates a separate thread prinicpal thread) for external connections. or perform any work that is likely to sue long the system